# Ampscript to find whether recipients in List or Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way we can use AMpscript to find if the source of the data is a List or a Data extension?

We are looking to create a content box with the ampscript that retrieves the correct footer content box in a email during send. This is based on what recipient source is selected (List or Data Extension) by the marketer. The content will be different based on this and I want Ampcript to find the source object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to check the value of  %%_listname%% at send time.  It will be blank if you send to a DE, otherwise the name of the list is there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's failing validation.  The only advice is make sure the corresponding fields are there.   A way around this is to have all the DE fields as attributes and leave them blank.